# Strophe.js + OpenFire + HTTPS not working

Tags: ssl, openfire, strophe

I am using `Strophe` library to connect to an `openfire` XMPP server.

**Question1** : can `strophe.js` handle **https** BOSH connection (on port 7443) ?

I am able to connect over http but failed when try to use over **https**.

In openfire admin console **HTTP Bind Settings is enabled**

My **proxy rule setting** in Apache as below :

```
# XMPP proxy rule
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /bosh https://127.0.0.1:7443/http-bind/
ProxyPassReverse /bosh https://127.0.0.1:7443/http-bind/
```

In code:

```
var connection=null;
var BOSH_URL :'https://localhost:7443/http-bind/';
connection = new Strophe.Connection(BOSH_URL);
connection.connect(jid,
                   password,
                   User.onConnect);
```

// Note: callback and everything is working ok over http, so i am not writing full code.

When Run above code, i am getting below error in browser console.

```
 https://localhost:7443/http-bind/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I have also tried below:

Just open url in browser :http://localhost:7070/http-bind/?
 and get response.[no problem here]

but when try https://localhost:7433/http-bind/? page will not load

Comment: Did you got any solution? I am also having same issue.